# set the height of the rows for rowDataBound method

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I have the following codes:

```
protected void exampleGridView_RowDataBound(object o, GridViewRowEventArgs e)


  {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            e.Row.Cells[0].Width = new Unit("150px");
            e.Row.Cells[1].Width = new Unit("5px");
            e.Row.Cells[2].Width = new Unit("150px");
            e.Row.Cells[3].Width = new Unit("150px");
            e.Row.Cells[4].Width = new Unit("150px");
            e.Row.Cells[5].Width = new Unit("150px");
            e.Row.Cells[6].Width = new Unit("150px");
            // and so on
        }
    }
```

Will it be possible to set the height of the cells as well? 
Thanks!

Comment: I think its ASP.NET not asp-classic as tagged,

Comment: i tried with e.Row.Cells[0].Height = new Unit("25px"); but its not really changing the height of the row

Comment: Please try :e.Row.Cells[0].Height=25;

Answer (score 1):

You are setting width at RowDataBound() event. You cannot do that, try columns property before databind() occurs.

Example

```
GridView1.CellPadding = 20;
GridView1.RowStyle.Height = 80;
```

or 
you can try this sample

in aspx:

```
 <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound" AutoGenerateColumns="false"
        runat="server">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="CatID" HeaderText="ID" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="CatName" HeaderText="Name" />
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

in .cs:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<Category> _lstCategory = new List<Category>{new Category { CatID = 1, CatName = "Cat1" }, 
                                                        new Category { CatID=2,CatName="Cat2" }};
    //GridView1.CellPadding = 20;
    //GridView1.RowStyle.Height = 80;
    GridView1.DataSource = _lstCategory;
    GridView1.DataBind();

}
public class Category
{
    public int CatID { get; set; }
    public string CatName { get; set; }
}
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    e.Row.Cells[1].Width = 100;
    e.Row.Cells[0].Width = 1;
}
```

it works for me.

Comment: sorry i'm new to asp, how should i do that?

Comment: @user1781830 i just updated my earlier reply with a code. pls check.